# addeventlistener for 'keypress' = captcha alternative?

Tags: javascript, validation, captcha, addeventlistener

Am I right in thinking that spam bots can't simulate the 'keypress' event, and thus I can't get spammed if I require a keypress for each field in my contact form before being able to submit it?

Is this a good alternative to captcha, etc. if I don't care whether or not my viewers have JavaScript enabled?

Wizards, set me right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure if they can generate the keypress event "natively" (I think you might be right that they can't, but it wouldn't surprise me to learn that there's some edge case whereby this is possible).

However, I don't think they would have a problem merely executing `element.onkeypress()` directly.  If the bot can determine that it needs to press a key to advance, then what that actually boils down to is that a particular event handler method needs to be invoked - and the bot *can* do the latter.  It can create its own fake Event object too containing the keycode, and then pass this in and/or set it on `window.event`.

In theory you *might* be able to detect this by being very strict about instrospecting the event object in your handler.  I don't think that the bot would easily be able to create a native-equivalent event object, so perhaps by inspecting the prototype chain you could distringuish between the two.  However, this would almost certainly be too fragile for general use, and is not going to reliably work across different browsers/environments/plugins/etc.

Thus I don't think this is a fruitful path, because you can't tell in an event handler whether the event is "real" or not.  Browser-native code is different, since bots cannot actually trigger a click event, but within Javascript I don't see a simple way to prevent your method from simply being called.

Comment: When you say that a bot can't trigger a click event, do you mean that by using an onClick button instead of a submit button would make me safe?

Comment: What I mean is that (IE aside) there's no way to simulate an *actual* click event in Javascript.  Of course, you can try to work out what the effects would have been and make them happen (e.g. get the `href` element of a link and navigate to it).  But you can't say "hey, browser, I just clicked here - take the appropriate action now".  So to answer your question, probably not; a bot could just manually run `button.onClick()`.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle what about mousemove?

Comment: @Shane Everything in my answer applies equally to *any* native JS event/listener.  It's still just functions - and it's no more challenging to call `element.onmousemove()` than it is to call `element.onkeypress()`.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle your right. And I learned in the past couple days that the script for these bots use it after testing this in a recent site.

Answer (score 0):

The current implementations of spambots might not be able to do that. But it's not that hard to simulate keypresses. If you're only a small website the bot author might not do the work to circumvent your system, but if it large enough for the auther to care your system will be broken really quick.